# How to send data in sencha between 2 views

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope

im learning sencha and i could not do data transfer between two views. I have 2 views. first view has datalist. when datalist item clicked im opening another view. and i need to send the list item values  to second view.

can anyone help me please?

first view.

```
Ext.define('griddeneme.view.pnlAna', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.pnlana',

requires: [
    'Ext.XTemplate'
],

config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 1,
            style: 'background-color:#81BEF7',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    docked: 'left',
                    height: 15,
                    itemId: 'mybutton1',
                    style: 'margin-Top',
                    ui: 'decline',
                    text: 'Çıkış'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 9,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'list',
                    flex: 1,
                    itemId: 'mylist',
                    itemTpl: [
                        '<div>{ad} - {yazar}</div>'
                    ],
                    store: 'strYazarlar'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    listeners: [
        {
            fn: 'onMybutton1Tap',
            event: 'tap',
            delegate: '#mybutton1'
        },
        {
            fn: 'onMylistItemTap',
            event: 'itemtap',
            delegate: '#mylist'
        }
    ]
},

onMybutton1Tap: function(button, e, eOpts) {

    var pnlAna = Ext.create('griddeneme.view.pnlGiris');



    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(pnlAna);
},

onMylistItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    //alert(record.data.ad);

    var Details=Ext.create('griddeneme.view.pnlDetail');
        Details.setData(record);

    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Details);
}
```

});

second view

```
Ext.define('griddeneme.view.pnlDetail', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.pnldetail',

config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 1,
            style: 'background-color:#81BEF7',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    docked: 'left',
                    height: 15,
                    ui: 'back',
                    text: 'Geri'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 8,
            itemId: 'mypanel7',
            style: '',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html: 'Kitap Adı:',
                    id: '',
                    minWidth: 150,
                    style: 'color:green; float:left'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html: 'f',
                    id: 'lblAd'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html: 'Yazar:',
                    minWidth: 150,
                    style: 'float:left;color:green;'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html: 'ggg',
                    id: 'lblKitap'
                }
            ],
            listeners: [
                {
                    fn: function(component, eOpts) {
                        alert(record.data.ad);
                    },
                    event: 'initialize'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

});

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to send to another view? I see that you're trying to create a `Panel` and use `setData` method? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.define('griddeneme.view.pnlDetail', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.pnldetail',

config: {
    someData: null,
    ...
```

And on instantiating your pnlDetail:

```
onMylistItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {

    var Details=Ext.create('griddeneme.view.pnlDetail',{
        someData: // here you can set your data
    });

    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Details);
}
```

Comment: thanks michel but i couldnt add someData varriable in pnldetail. Haw can i do ?

Comment: What happens if you add someData property to your panels config?

Comment: itemtap:

var Details=Ext.create('griddeneme.view.pnlDetail',{data : record.getData()});

Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Details);




onpanelinitialize;

var data=this.config.data;
alert(data.ad);

I wrote it and its work. is it true ?